# Each modified code must be manually regenerated for vs2019 community version,otherwise,not work

Tags: c#, .net

On vs2019 community version,Each modified code must be manually regenerated, otherwise, the code will not work.i don't know why. On the VS2019 professional version, all is ok.

Reset "Tools" -> "Options"->"Project and solution" -> "Build and run", not work
[image]

After revise the code, click the run button on vs, vs should rebuild all the code changed and launch, but vs load the old dll to work.The breakpoint would be invalid if i don't rebuild the dll code.

[image]

Comment: Try doing a clean, delete all Bin and Obj directories, see if this happens with a fresh project if it does try reinstall/repair visual studio as it seems like a bug

Comment: do the clean solution and delete all pdb files, Rebuild the code, the breakpoint should work, but if i changed the code and set the breakpoint on the new code. F5 to run, the breakpoint still invalid.

Comment: Does this happen on new projects?

Comment: The project combined by some libraries, if build new one console project, change the code and set the breakpoint, the breakpoint is valid. i don't know why.

Comment: Is your configuration set to build these projects in your solution -> properties -> conflagration properties ?

Comment: yes , set all the sub project as build status and checked.

Comment: Does this happen on new projects?

Comment: Is the community version no right to do that?

Comment: I think i know how to fix the question, "Tools" -> "Options"->"Project and solution" -> "Build and run", uncheck the item "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run". Because on my code, use some layouts(DLL) to manage, so should be uncheck the item to rebuild all DLLs when lanuch. thanks

Comment: If its working for you, maybe it will work for someone else, Write up a well formatted answer